# Как сгенерировать SVG спрайт?

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-спрайт

чтобы обращаться по id к картинке

Answer (score 1):

Есть много онлайн сервисов для генерации SVG sprite. Просто накидываете своих svg и сайт вам выдаст уже готовый sprite из svg

1. [svgsprit.es](https://svgsprit.es/)
2. [Генератор SVG спрайтов](https://products.aspose.app/svg/ru/svg-sprite-generator)